# Undefied result from Xml with Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath, undefined

I know this has been asked in diffrent situations before...

...But I'm following w3schools example --> http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryit.asp?filename=try_xpath_select_cdnodes_first

What I'm trying to do is to call my function and return the result but I keep getting the Undefined result. the goal is to get the value of a node in this XML document

```
<curriculum>    
    <Course Name="Slyngel">
        <StartDate>2014-09-04</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2014-09-10</EndDate>
        <Heading>My heading</Heading>
        <Info>This is some info about the course</Info>
        <Subheading>Course Include</Subheading>
        <Body>
            <Item>This</Item>
            <Item>And This</Item>
            <Item>And This</Item>
        </Body>
        <Price>2000</Price>
        </Course>
</curriculum>
```

Code

```
function DisplayInfo(courseName, node) {
    var x = loadXMLDoc("Xml/CourseInfo.xml");
    var xml = x.responseXML;
    path = "/curriculum/Course[@Name='" + courseName + "']/" + node;
    var resultValue ="";

// code for IE
    if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document") {
        xml.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath");
        var nodes = xml.selectNodes(path);

        return nodes.childNodes[0].nodeValue;        
    }
// code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
    else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {
        var nodes = xml.evaluate(path, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
        var result = nodes.iterateNext();

        return result.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  }    

}
```

This is the result I get when trying to call the function with these lines of codes.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qz112.jpg

```
var InfoHeaderText = GetCourseInfo('Heading');
InfoHeader.innerHTML = (InfoHeaderText);    

var InfoInfoText = InfoHeaderText = GetCourseInfo('Info');
InfoInfo.innerHTML = (InfoInfoText);
```

Comment: Maybe doesn't solve the problem, but you're sure about the line 
var InfoInfoText = InfoHeaderText = GetCourseInfo('Info'); ?

Comment: yes... GetCourseInfo() has one parameter thats for the node name. GetCourseInfo then calls DisplayInfo with two attributes one from a http parameter(the attribute = name) and then the node name. it looks like this: function GetCourseInfo(node) {
    var CourseName = GetURLParameter('Course');
    DisplayInfo(CourseName, node);
}

thx for your response thoe

Comment: misunderstanding; I didn't question the function getcourseinfo(), but the assignment of the variable in the 2nd last line; it's like "var a = b = c;" instead of "var a = c;" I think it's better to change that into  "var InfoInfoText = GetCourseInfo('Info');" as this kind of assignment leads to js-errors

Comment: I have not seen that, thats ofc wrong. thank u very much !